# Import error with Gulp and Babel when upgrading to ES2017

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I have ES6 gulp modules for automation in my project. Within them there are JS features you would expect such as imports. In order for this to work I have babel and ES2015 preset installed. My `.babelrc` file looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Everything works perfectly. Now I want to try upgrading to ES2017 which I believe was released recently so I assume has a completed spec (am I wrong about this?).

I install `babel-preset-es2017` and change the `.babelrc` to:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2017"]
}
```

Now nothing works and I get a basic error on using import:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

So clearly something has gone wrong here and it's not happy compiling gulp on the fly with a newer babel preset. Any ideas why?

I just want to use the newest JS version that is fully released with a finished spec and is actively maintained.

Comment: Have you tried having both in the array? ```["es2015", "es2017"]```

Comment: I haven't, but I can't see why that would be necessary. Surely you don't have to specify every spec/year? Wouldn't I then have to do `['es2015', 'es2016', 'es2017']` to get all the features?

Comment: According to this link - https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2017/ - "ES2017 preset - Only compiles what's in ES2017 to ES2016", so you'd possibly need to do just that - ```['es2015', 'es2016', 'es2017']```

Comment: @BogdanMartinescu Interesting, I hadn't thought about it that way. Thanks for the link - this seems to work now!